# flask-socketio send message when thread finishes

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, subprocess, flask-socketio

I have a Python flask script (using [flask-socketio](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) which hosts a website with a few buttons. When I click on one of the buttons the browser send a request via socket.io to the server. The server then starts a function in a new thread. I would like to send a message back to the client when the thread has finished but I can't get it to work.

```
@socketio.on('login', namespace='/command')
def login_account(data):
    data = json.loads(data)
    emit('response', {'command':"login", 'response': 1})
    login = Thread(target=do_login, args=(data["id"],))
    login.start()
    while login.isAlive() == True:
        time.sleep(2)
    emit('response', {"command":"login", 'title':"Melde  " + data["name"].decode('utf-8') + " an", 'response': data["name"].decode('utf-8') + " erfolgreich angemeldet. Verbinde dich per VNC um mit dem Account zu interagieren."}, namespace='/command')
```

`do_login` does some things with a Selenium WebDriver and starts `x11vnc` on Seleniums display. The whole thing worked great until I added the `x11vnc` subprocess:

```
subprocess.call('x11vnc -display:' + str(display.display) +" 2>/dev/null 1>&2 &", shell=True)
```

Since then I always get the following in the browsers console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://somehost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=f1164e481c0f44338b3e952f01830a90' failed: Invalid frame header
```

On the server I get:

```
Client disconnected
84.187.79.227 - - [21/Feb/2016 12:14:26] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x88\x9a\xc9\x9aVA\xcap\x01$\xab\xc99"\xa2\xff"a\x99\xe895\xa6\xf99-\xe9\xdf$3\xa6\xe8')
84.187.79.227 - - [21/Feb/2016 12:14:26] "??ɚVA?p$??9"??"a??95??9-??$3??" 400 -
```

I also tried using `from eventlet.green import subprocess` but it did not help.

My client code is:

```
command = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + "/command");
command.on('response', function(data) {
  var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
  if (data["command"] == "login"){
    if (data["response"] == "1"){
      HoldOn.open({
        theme:"sk-folding-cube"
      });
    }
    else{
      HoldOn.close();
      $('#modal_information_title').text(data["title"]);
      $('#modal_information_body').text(data["response"]);
      $('#modal_information').modal('show');
    }
  }
      });
```

The button calls:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="command.emit('login', JSON.stringify({'name':'{{item['username']}}', 'id':'{{item['id']}}'}));">Login</button>
```

**Update**

I am now using `XvncDisplay` instead of x11vnc but I still got the same issue. The whole thing works if I start the display and browser on script startup and than only do the login on button press. But I don't want to have the browser started when no one is using it, so that's not really a solution...

```
from pyvirtualdisplay.xvnc import XvncDisplay
display = XvncDisplay(rfbport='5900', size=(800, 700))
display.start()
```

Comment: Did you monkey patch the standard library?

Comment: Yes, I've patched it. No idea why it does not work anyway..